# Uploading and restoring image using nodejs, mongoDb, expressJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to upload image from my browser and store that in local file and add the file name in mongodb.
When I would like to retrieve the file the file stored in local folder should be shown in browser

Thank you,
Babji

Answer (score 0):

to upload image to local folder and save path to mongodb follow the below code..

```
app.post('/api/images', multipart(), function(req, res) {
    //Create folder to store image as per year and month
    console.log(path.resolve(__dirname));
    if (! fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname) + "/public/images/" + shortMonth[new Date().getMonth()] + "_" + new Date().getFullYear())) {
        fs.mkdir(path.resolve(__dirname) + "/public/images/" + shortMonth[new Date().getMonth()] + "_" + new Date().getFullYear());
    }
    var tempPath = req.files.file.path;
    var ext = path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase();
    var newFileName = '/images/' + shortMonth[new Date().getMonth()] + "_" + new Date().getFullYear() + "/" + genarateUniqueHash() + ext;
    console.log('newFileName:', newFileName);
    var targetPath = path.resolve('./public' + newFileName);
    if (ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif') {
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            res.send(200, {
                path: newFileName
            });
        });
    } else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function() {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(500, {
                error: 'Only image files are allowed.'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

and dont forget to use ng-file-upload if you use angular-js